# PostgreSQL create table char error

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I just started learning PostgreSQL. I tried to create a table:

```
create table diagnosis(
    mkb10 char(5),
    opis varchar(100) not null,
    constraint pk_diagnosis primary key (mkb10)
);
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "char"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X8M_9ORP)

Except that I never use the outdated data type `char(n)`. And [neither should you](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29). See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860)